# Communication between two Machines using java

Tags: java

I have  Gui Application written  which running on windows,and i want to connect to remote unix machine and perform actions there such like API's ,go over the log file in the machines and send back to the application the last log file or others API that i want to perform on the remote machine.

In the remote machine i don;t have application server i just have Java which installed there.

I want to use Java in order to perform remote API over the remote machine;

what is the advice ,can i use web services ,can any one please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If Java can perform the actions you're talking about, I would use [Sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) to communicate with the UNIX-Machine (over TCP/IP).

Your Windows-PC would be the client sending commands to the Unix-PC.

Comment: +1: Unless you a good reason to do otherwise, I would use a text based protocol so you can easily log and read what is being sent/recieved.

Answer (score 0):

Web services would be a bit heavy handed option, esp if you opt for the SOAP ones. If you don't have a problem with the client and server always being Java, RMI seems to be the simplest solution to this problem since it's communication between two different JVM's using the normal method calling mechanism (with some additional interfaces and rules to be followed to please the RMI specification).

Answer (score 0):

For analyzing log files of remote machines you can always use [Apache Commons sftp](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html#SFTP) programmatically to FTP a copy of the remote log file to your PC.

If you configure the log files to be rotatable or to rotate each time they reach a specific size, you can avoid reloading the same information over and over.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Framework ships with a number of [remoting options](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/remoting.html) that are all very easy to setup. You can use their classes for simpler configuration of something standard like RMI or JMS, or use a lightweight web services protocol such as Spring's HTTP invoker or Hessian.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ganymed SSH-2 for Java](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/) to ssh to the remote host from Client Java App and run the commands. No need to run any additional components on remote server. You can do password based authentication or key based authentication to login to remote host. We had successfully used it to administer (start/stop/grep log files, etc.) applications running on remote UNIX hosts. You can capture output of the remote command using the StreamGobbler class provided in the package. You can pass multiple commands separated by semi-colon in one remote call.

Basic Example included in the package:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Session;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.StreamGobbler;

public class Basic
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String hostname = "127.0.0.1";
        String username = "joe";
        String password = "joespass";

        try
        {
            /* Create a connection instance */

            Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);

            /* Now connect */

            conn.connect();

            /* Authenticate.
             * If you get an IOException saying something like
             * "Authentication method password not supported by the server at this stage."
             * then please check the FAQ.
             */

            boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);

            if (isAuthenticated == false)
                throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");

            /* Create a session */

            Session sess = conn.openSession();

            sess.execCommand("uname -a && date && uptime && who");

            System.out.println("Here is some information about the remote host:");

            /* 
             * This basic example does not handle stderr, which is sometimes dangerous
             * (please read the FAQ).
             */

            InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

            while (true)
            {
                String line = br.readLine();
                if (line == null)
                    break;
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            /* Show exit status, if available (otherwise "null") */

            System.out.println("ExitCode: " + sess.getExitStatus());

            /* Close this session */

            sess.close();

            /* Close the connection */

            conn.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,

Currently i am using Ganymed SSH for doing it , pur the problem of this that i all the time must send the request as unix commands such like 
sess.execCommand("uname -a && date && uptime && who")
and if i want to perfrom heavy logic in java code and using thread in java it;s problem